# jquery reorder divs

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 divs want to reverse the order on doucment ready

```
<div id="block-1">First</div>
<div id="block-2">Second</div>
<div id="block-3">Third</div>
```

How can I do this in jquery?

Comment: Why would you want to reverse them on document ready?  Why not just load them reversed initially?

Answer (score 20):

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="block-1">First</div>
<div id="block-2">Second</div>
<div id="block-3">Third</div>
</div>
```

And try this in Jquery

```
$('#parent > div').each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
});​
```

You can see example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N7PGW/

Comment: +1 for not being reliant on knowing the id of or number of divs in the parent.

Answer (score 12):

Just use

```
$('#block-2').insertBefore('#block-1');
$('#block-3').insertBefore('#block-2');
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2DUXF/

Answer (score 4):

This will reverse all divs inside a div with id "div1"

```
  $(function(){
    var items=$("#div1 div").toArray();
        items.reverse();
        $.each(items,function(){
           $("#div1").append(this); 
        });     
    });​
```

Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bCAVz/8/

Comment: I like the use of toArray() - in addition to the generic reverse() that was asked for I can also use it to randomize etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(
   $("div[id|=block]")
      .slice(1)
      .get()
      .reverse()
 )
    .insertBefore("div[id|=block]:first");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8adwS/

Also note that you can add the array reverse syntax to the jQuery function syntax, which would save you a selector.