# Alternate and hide divs using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a load of divs being output to the page with PHP and they have one of two classes either "cheese" or "wine":

```
<div class="cheese"></div>
<div class="wine"></div>
<div class="cheese"></div>
<div class="cheese"></div>
<div class="cheese"></div>
<div class="wine"></div>
```

How do I make them alternate using jquery? So that they look like this:

```
<div class="cheese"></div>
<div class="wine"></div>
<div class="cheese"></div>
<div class="wine"></div>
<div class="cheese"></div>
<div class="wine"></div>
```

Is it also possible to hide any divs if there is say two "cheese" divs at the end then hide the last one?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you actually want? Arrange the div or hide the div?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: That's too broad for me now... You can try checking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088496/jquery-reorder-divs and take it from there...

Comment: @j08691 Do you think my above comment can make a better dupe for this?

Comment: Arrange them in alternating order!

Comment: @PraveenKumar It's a starting point for the OP but I wouldn't close it as a dupe for it. Currently too broad as you noted.

Comment: Sure @j08691 Closing as too broad then...

Comment: How is it too broad?

Comment: @DanChapman Because, it's not specific to your problem. It's a general problem and many have answered. There are other questions, eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088496/jquery-reorder-divs to keep it as a starting point and work towards it... Go ahead... Try it out... If you fail, we are all here to help you.

Comment: slect them, remove them, readd them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could do it. Select all items first, they will be in unordered collection. Then sort all wine together followed by all cheese items.

After that, all you need to do is to append items in alternating order. I think simplest way to do it is to append them one by one taking items out of array, from the bottom (pop),then from the beginning (shift).

If you have uneven number of cheese or wine, then there might be duplicated items of the same type at the very end of the list. You can hide those excess items using sibling CSS selector (`.wine + .wine`).

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.cheese, .wine')

const sorted = [...items].sort((a, b) => {
  return a.className === b.className ? -1 : 1
})

while (sorted.length) {
  let item = sorted.length % 2 ? sorted.shift() : sorted.pop()
  container.appendChild(item)
}
```

```css
/* hide repeating items */
.cheese + .cheese,
.wine + .wine {
  display: none;
}

/* visual styles */
.cheese,
.wine {
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.cheese {
  background: yellow;
}

.wine {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cheese"></div>
  <div class="wine"></div>
  <div class="wine"></div>
  <div class="wine"></div>
  <div class="cheese"></div>
  <div class="cheese"></div>
  <div class="wine"></div>
  <div class="wine"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works absolutely perfectly - THANK YOU SO MUCH!!